# Cannot connect to RabbitMQ server

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm trying to run the sample code, provided by the official page:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html

I'm using this code:

```
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;
using System;

class Send
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "rabbit@my.host.name.net" };
        var connection = factory.CreateConnection() //this throwing exception
        var channel = connection.CreateModel()
    }
}
```

The problem is, that I get these exceptions always:

> 'RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException'
>   in RabbitMQ.Client.dll 
>   'RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException' in
>   RabbitMQ.Client.dll

The server is not running on the localhost, so I have changed the hostname to my server hostname.  I can reach the server from my computer with ping and the server is listening on the 5672 port.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Did you check firewall? Can you telnet to 5672 port?

Comment: Since I can ping the hostname the firewall cannot be a problem

Comment: Yes I tried to telnet and it works fine.

Comment: This is not true. 5672 port should be open, and the fact you can ping your host does not mean it is open.

Comment: Then you need to check details of that ConnectFailureException. What's its message? Any inner exceptions?

Comment: Yes, you a right. I tried telnet to 5672 and it worked.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/n6SHj3u.png  Here is a screenshot about the main exception

Comment: Did you give access rights to the user "rabbit" - to exchange, vhost etc?

Comment: I tried with guest which is the default account for RMQ and doesn't work either. I have not set any policies to restrict connection. However the rabbit@....  is just the clustername, not refering to username.

Comment: I think its pretty clear that rabbitmq server is not reachable from the machine where you are running your client from the [image](http://i.imgur.com/n6SHj3u.png) you posted. Can you try `ip-address` instead of the `hostname` of the machine where you rabbitmq server is running ?

Comment: Yes I tried, but not helped. I can login to the management GUI from my browser like http.://my.host.name.net:15672/ and typing username/password and everything is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so few things from the comments:

`However the rabbit@.... is just the clustername, not refering to username` 
Even though I'm not familiar with C# API, I'm quite sure that this is **not the way** to write the hostname. You should only write the IP first, see if it works, and then with the hostname. If you want to you can use the API to provide [the AMQP URI](https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html).

Cluster is something for the broker itself; the clients shouldn't care if they are connecting to a node in the cluster, or a single ("non-clustered") instance...

Secondly, "guest" **user which is used by default** (if no user is specified) can only access the broker from localhost (again, by default). So if you are trying to connect from another computer to the server, with "guest" will not work. You need to create a new RMQ user and assign proper permissions.

Note that you can of course configure RMQ in that way that the guest user has access (which would be very wrong even for dev environment, even if you change the default password), official RMQ docker image is configured in that way (was last time I checked anyhow).

Comment: Thank your your helpful answer. The fact is, that first I just wanted to connect to the host any possible way. After that I would refine my methods.

Also I tried with IP address to, but didn't work. I tried with not guest account too, not helping.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you need to use right .NET runtime. For example [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html) for RabbitMQ it states. 4.x and 5.x release series of this library require .NET 4.5.1+ or a .NET Standard 1.5+ implementation (e.g. .NET Core 2.x). This just happened to a collegue, he found updating the runtime fixed the problem and the log messages gave little clue as to the cause.